# Get mysql results from table with date_time more than 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query, the target is to get all profile IDs from a table that contains profiles in which user's last activity 30 minutes or more, or there was no activity recorded from that user at all (activity log recorded in another table).

The problem is: the results are 0 even there are records of more than 30 minutes old, I have checked few answers here, and followed the instructions and yet there are no results return, I think there's something wrong with the structure of the query.

below is the query, please note that profiles are stored in profile_table and activities are stored in activity_table and both share the same ID.

```
$sql = "select ID from profile_table where status = 'Active' AND (ID in (select ID from activity_table where date_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) or ID NOT IN (select ID from activity_table))"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this query.
select pr.ID from profile_table pr left join activity_table ac on pr.ID=ac.ID where pr.status='Active' and ac.date_time< DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)